# How to reset or clear in vbash?

Tags: linux, bash, router

I am logged into my Edge router terminal over SSH. As I usually do after a few long commands, I typed in `reset`:

```
admin@ERX:~$ reset                                           
Incomplete command                               
admin@ERX:~$ reset -h                                                        
Invalid command
admin@ERX:~$ reset --help                                         
Invalid command                                      
admin@ERX:~$ reset help
Invalid command
admin@ERX:~$ which reset
/usr/bin/reset
admin@ERX:~$ clear
Incomplete command
admin@ERX:~$ which clear
/usr/bin/clear
```

Now, I know that edge routers come bundled with a specific fork of `bash`, namely `vbash` ([VyOS](https://vyos.io)).

```
admin@ERX:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/vbash
```

I can type in the whole command (with path) to reset, but why isn't vbash picking up the commands if no alternative definitions exist?

```
admin@ERX:~$ vbash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.0(2)-release (mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Are `reset` and `clear` being overridden? If so, why does `which <command>` not report the same?

---

### UPDATE 1

Output of `PATH`

```
admin@ERX:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like bash has aliases defined for 'reset' and 'clear' which are used when you call them without the full path.

`which` is an external tool, not a bash builtin, so it does not know about aliases.

Check the output of `alias` if aliases for 'reset' and 'clear' are defined.